Событие contextmenu на IOS не вызывается при Long Press
Есть проблема. Используется WKWebView + JS.
На андройд, если делать longpress, то элемент верстки получит событие contextmenu. Пытаясь сделать то же самое на IOS я обнаружил, что события просто нет.
Немного погуглив, я узнал, что с 13 версии IOS contextmenu не вызывается вообще. Как в таком случае быть?
Из идей, попробовать отслеживать на нативке longpress и сообщать об этом фронту. На фронте же отслеживать touchstart/touchend и плясать от этого.
Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Можно ли включить событие contextmenu или имитировать его?
Вариант с отслеживанием longpress на js не подходит.

Посмотрите https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/3335223-webview
